# In Spring, how can I autopopulate a custom argument to a web @Controller method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In Spring, I can use a `Principal` object as an argument to a web controller method, and it gets populated.  For example:

```
public String listTransactionsForAccount(Model model, Principal principal) {
    String username = principal.getName();
    // do something with the username
}
```

My question is this: How can I pass in a custom object (`Account`) and have it populate, similar to how Spring populates the `Principal`?

In my application model, I've got a setup where there are 0..n `User`s per `Account`.  I can get the User based off of the `Principal` but what I'm really after is the `Account`.  I find that I have to do this in a lot of places:

```
String username = principal.getName();
User user = userService.findByUsername(username);
Long accountId = user.getAccount().getId();
```

It would be ideal if I could just do this:

```
public String listTransactionsForAccount(Model model, Account account) {
    // do stuff directly with the account
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html most likely

Answer (score 2):

You can use @ModelAttribute parameters and methods

Below is one of a way to achieve it

```
 public class AController {
     @Autowired
     private Object someBean;

      @ModelAttribute
      public void setAccount(Model model)
      {
           model.addAttrbute("account", new Account());
            //you can use some injected object to retrieve account object
            //ex someBean.getAccountFactory().getInstance();
      }

      @RequestMapping
      public Strig yourMethod (@ModelAttribute("account") Account ac,Model model {
        ///your code
      }
```

The first method would be called before the second and it will populate Account into Model. This will be injected into second method

Answer (score 0):

@RC is right... (post that as an answer and I'll accept it)

What I did is as follows:

```
@Component
public class AccountHandlerMethodArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Override
public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter, ModelAndViewContainer mvContainer,
        NativeWebRequest request, WebDataBinderFactory webDataBinderFactory) throws Exception {
    Account account = null;
    Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
    if (principal != null) {
        String email = principal.getName();
        User user = userService.findByEmail(email);
        if (user != null) {
            account = user.getAccount();
        }
    }
    return account;
}

@Override
public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
    return methodParameter.getParameterType().equals(Account.class);
}

}
```

As long as spring picks up the class above (via component scan, or bean declaration), the `Account` value is populated in a method like this:

```
@Controller
public class TxController {

public String listTransactionsForAccount(Model model, Account account) {
    ....
}
....
}
```